# Automatic Jenkins deployment in websphere

Tags: java, svn, jenkins, websphere

i need to deploy ear/war file from svn to websphere using jenkins job ?
i have different environment. By using svn tag name and environment details i need to do deploy in different environment websphere.

can any one suggest me how will i achieve this ?

Comment: Well, I would tag this question as too broad... The only thing I can tell you is that you need to talk to the Websphere agent you want to deploy to. I am not sure if there's a built Script for Websphere deployment for Jenkins, but it seems as if you first goal is to understand your needs exactly and then see what tools are available, and develop the missing parts...

Comment: Also specify what WebSphere version are you using, full or Liberty, and whether it is local or remote server.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you with the second part of your question. This is a plugin to deploy jenkins artifacts on

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebSphere+Deployer+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to do this by jenkins plugin, but it works bad. It can not support multiply node and the ssl management is also boring.
So i sujest you use the ant shell in the target machine for deployment.